# How can I do FOCAL MECHANISMS on Generic Mapping Tools (GMT)?

Tags: gis, geo

I've made some FOCAL MECHANISMS (FM) for the north part of Southamerica on [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/), and I need to put them on a map.

For the FM I have a document with 85 earthquakes and this is the code:

```
psmeca eventos2.dat -R-80/-66/-5/14 -JM6i -Sm0.4/0/0.05u -P -V > coltopomap.ps
GMT psconvert coltopomap.ps -Tf
```

And this is the map

```
GMT grdcut topo15.grd -R-80/-66/-5/14 -Gtopo15_cut_col.grd
GMT grdgradient topo15_cut_col.grd -Gtopo15_cut_shaded.grd -A310 -Ne0.6
GMT grdimage topo15_cut_col.grd -JM6i -R-80/-66/-5/14 -Cglobe -P -Ba --MAP_FRAME_TYPE=plain --MAP_GRID_CROSS_SIZE_PRIMARY=0p -Itopo15_cut_shaded.grd -K > coltopomap.ps 
GMT pscoast -R-80/-66/-5/14 -J -Df -N1/1,black -W1/0.5,black -Lf-68/-4/-68/-4/200k+l -Tdg-78/12+w0.3i+f3+lW,E,S,N --FONT_ANNOT=10p --FONT_LABEL=10p --FONT_TITLE=10p -O >> coltopomap.ps
```

To join them I've tried with

```
GMT grdcut topo15.grd -R-80/-66/-5/14 -Gtopo15_cut_col.grd
GMT grdgradient topo15_cut_col.grd -Gtopo15_cut_shaded.grd -A310 -Ne0.6
GMT grdimage topo15_cut_col.grd -JM6i -R-80/-66/-5/14 -Cglobe -P -Ba --MAP_FRAME_TYPE=plain --MAP_GRID_CROSS_SIZE_PRIMARY=0p -Itopo15_cut_shaded.grd -K > coltopomap.ps 
GMT pscoast -R-80/-66/-5/14 -J -Df -N1/1,black -W1/0.5,black -Lf-68/-4/-68/-4/200k+l -Tdg-78/12+w0.3i+f3+lW,E,S,N --FONT_ANNOT=10p --FONT_LABEL=10p --FONT_TITLE=10p -O >> coltopomap.ps
GMT psmeca eventos2.dat -R-80/-66/-5/14 -JM6i -Sm0.4/0/0.05u -P -V >> coltopomap.ps
GMT psconvert coltopomap.ps -Tf
```

But the only thing I get is the map in one page and the FM in another as you can see in the next image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAvx7.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the `-K` flag from your `GMT pscoast ...` command.

From [GMT documentation](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/doc/latest/gmt.html#k-full):

> Required for all but the last plot command when building multi-layer
>   plots